# Accessing table(s) in current HTML page from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to Chrome extension, and I decided to make one. Now, I need to access tables in a page, and how many are there, I can already achieve that by executing `$(document).find("table")` and `$(document).find("table").length` respectively but from the document using the console, but, I tried `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` in extension etc, but I can't find a way to access this data from the extension. Any help please?

Here's my code:

**popup.js**:

```
var numOfTables = 0;
function getNumOfTables() {
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    alert($(document).find("table").length);
    var tablesResult = $(document).find("table").length;
    numOfTables = tablesResult;
    $("#mainParagraph").text("We found " + numOfTables + " in this page");
    });
};
getNumOfTables();
```

**popup.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
 This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
 "browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
 value "popup.html".
 -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
     -->
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id="header">HTML Table to Excel</h2>
    <p id="mainParagraph"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't really need anything complex, just need a way to execute `$(document).find("table")` in the current tab from the extension and get the result, executeScript should work, but i don't think it can return the value of a function. Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to give a little more detail.  How did you try execute script?

Comment: I'll edit the question with more details

Comment: @Teepeemm Btw i had a mistake, i used `chrome.tabs.getCurrent`, not executeScript, check edited question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're trying to access the current tab.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
  /* and you are not using tab! */
});
```

Just running this will not magically refer to the tab; `document` still refers to `popup.html`, and therefore you don't find anything.

Take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) to understand *why* you need a content script.

So, you need to inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) with `executeScript` and somehow report the result back. [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) will help you with that.

You will also need to include your own copy of jQuery to use `$`, since it's a different context from the page.

---

First off, you'll need permissions. If you're going to inject into current tab from the popup, `"activeTab"` is enough.

Then, you can inject with this:

```
// popup.js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  null,                      // Current tab
  {file: "jquery.js"},        // Script to inject
  function() {               // Something to do afterwards
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"}, afterInject);
  }
);
```

In your content script, get ready to answer queries.

```
// content.js

// Ensure it's injected only once
var injected;
if(!injected) {
  injected = true;
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
}

function handleMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch(message.action) {
    case "getNumOfTables":
      sendResponse($(document).find("table").length);
    default:
      console.error("Unknown request from extension");
  }
}
```

Finally, from your popup, you can send a message to request this action:

```
// Make sure it happens after the inject
function afterInject(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "getNumOfTables"}, function(result) {
      // Use the result here
    });
  });
}
```

Not sure if this code will be useful without in-depth explanations, but it's a starting point.

Comment: In the executeScript part, i think there should be a colon after `{link: "jquery.js"}` right?